# playing animation when audio is recording

Tags: android, animation

i am developing virtual cigaratte in which i am using images and frame animation i want to play animation when audio is recording... can any give idea about this apps?

my code is below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView imageView;
AnimationDrawable animation;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myanim);
    animation=(AnimationDrawable)imageView.getBackground();
}
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        animation.start();
    }
    else {
        animation.stop();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView imageView;
Button record,stop;
AnimationDrawable animation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
record   =(Button)findViewById(R.id.record);
stop     =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myanim);
animation=(AnimationDrawable)imageView.getBackground();

record.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
  //do your function of record
  animation.start();
}}

stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
  //do your function of record
  animation.stop();
}}

}


}
```

Comment: thanks but i am not using button when i give voice input than animation will be play other wise stop...